# htaccess mod-rewrite concat rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\?([A-Za-z-]+)$ $1&msg=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)$ /?goTo=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^account/([A-Za-z-]+)$ /?goTo=account&section=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)edit=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^account/?$ /?goTo=account&act=edit_%1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)return=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^access/?$ /?goTo=access&return=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

The part I'm having troubles with is `RewriteRule ^(.+)\?([A-Za-z-]+)$ $1&msg=$2 [L,NC]`.

Basically when I go to `mysite.com/account/user` it corresponds to `mysite.com?goTo=account&section=user`.
If I go to `mysite.com/account/user?editSucc` I need to get `mysite.com?goTo=account&section=user&msg=editSucc`.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need QSA flag in 2nd rule and don't need first rule at all:

```
RewriteRule ^account/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ /?goTo=account&section=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)edit=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^account/?$ /?goTo=account&act=edit_%1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)return=([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^access/?$ /?goTo=access&return=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

- Remember `RewriteRule` doesn't match QUERY_STRING
- QSA flag is for appending existing query string into new query parameters

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)